# Which version of the extension builder is working for TYPO3 9.5 LTS?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

It is recommend to use a recent version from Github https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder.

The latest version of the master branch does not work for the current LTS version of TYPO3 and I don't find any tags 9.x at all on Github.

In the extension manager the master branch identifies already as 9.10.0 so I have hope there is a working version for TYPO3 9.5 LTS. Which version is it?

If there is no working version for 9.t LTS, what is your workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today a working approach for TYPO3 9.5 LST is this:

Latest commit of master:

ad22d356546794cecfe436ad2d3e3290933f3693

Manual fix of the save bug as given here by the user qbadev:

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder/issues/178